# Display Message in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

I want to display message in my dialog. I have a function call on button :

```
checkDialogSubmit: function(dialog) {
        var hrefField = this.getFieldByName("href");     
        var hrefValue = hrefField.getValue();         
        if(hrefValue.indexOf('/val/')==-1 ){  
            //print message on dialog
            return false;
        }      
        else{          
            this.apply();
        }
        return true;
    },
```

And Here is my button and dialog configuration. I need the message should come on the top of all dialog items.

```
constructor: function(config) {
        config = config || { };
        var defaults = {
            "title": CQ.I18n.getMessage("Hyperlink"),
            "dialogItems": [ 
                    {
                    items
                }
        ],
 "buttons": [ { "itemId": "okButton", "name": "okButton", "text": CQ.I18n.getMessage("Ok"), "handler": this.checkDialogSubmit, "disabled": false, "scope": this }, { "itemId": "cancelButton", "name": "cancelButton", "text": CQ.I18n.getMessage("Cancel"), "handler": this.cancel, "disabled": false, "scope": this }
            ]
        };
        CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, defaults);
        CQ.form.rte.plugins.LinkDialog.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `CQ.Ext.Msg.alert('Your Message');` or `CQ.Ext.Msg.show()` ?

Comment: Yes, I have used this, these display the message or alert boxes, But I want to display message inside dialog, same as like fieldLabel with bold on top of dialogItems.

Comment: If you want to show an error on the dialog, you can use `markInvalid()` method on the field which needs to be corrected.

Comment: Thanks Rakhi, but when I place this.markInvalid('wrong path') inside my checkDialogSubmit function (place where //print message on dialog) it gives me an error like Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Ignore last comment : Now when I place hrefField.markInvalid('Sample Text');   inside my checkDialogSubmit function it shows its red means invalid. But how can i display text in dialog as well like message. But still it can work as we can see text by hover it, Bit if you have an idea please share. Thanks

Comment: Ok this can be achieved by adding a xtype label as a field in dialog. show the message when error occurred and hide the message if no errors are present. if(error) {CQ.Ext.getCmp("id of the label field in dialog").setText("error msg").setVisible(true);}//by default field should be hidden which can be done by configuring hidden: true or setVisible(false); Let me know if this worked. API widget docs http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.Label

Answer (score 0):

```
var pDialog = CQ.WCM.getDialog("/apps/global/components/general/damassetwhitelistdialog/damassetwhitelistdialog");
pDialog.show();
```

and in dialog just add a panel with message in it.